# Grafana instant query option is returning empty results

Tags: time-series, prometheus, grafana, metrics, promql

From last few days we are seeing `Instant` query in Grafana is not working and returning empty results. This used to work fine earlier.

We enabled `Instant` query to have accurate results in Stat visualisation. If disabled we are getting incorrect results. We are using below query and visualising results in Stat visualisation.

`sum(increase(abc_volume_action_count{kube_cluster_name="$xyz",controller="provision",result="completed"}[$__range]))`

- Grafana v7.5.6
- Is there a way we can display accurate counter type metrics results without using `Instant` query ? or
- way to debug in Grafana why `Instant` option is not working.

Any help ? . Attached screen shots for reference. [image: Instant enabled][image: Instant disabled]